# Android REST user authentication (csrf token error)

Tags: php, android, symfony

I have successfully integrated the HWIOAuthBundle in my Symfony2 project and user registration and login is working very well(using facebook,google and fosuser login).

Now, i am planning to develop an android application of my Symfony2 web application.
I wonder how can i manage user authentication and registration restfully.

I've searched a lot and i didn't any good response which has surprised me a lot knowing that the HWIOAuthBundle is commonly used.

i do simply send the username login and password as post variables to my login route does it work?i  had problems with the csrf token used in login form

So, I would be thankful if somebody can tell me THE RIGHT WAY to implement REST Authentication using HWIOAuthBundle.

Comment: HWIOAuthBundle is sort of authentication client which authenticated you against OAuth service providers. Its not an authentication server!!

Comment: where can i find the OAuth service providers?